# android: Sort List after Adding items to the existing list using RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which shows list of items sorted in descending order that works fine when I initially launch the screen, but when I add some more items to the existing list and setting it to the adapter with notifyDataSetChanged() method the existing list gets sorted in ascending order and the new items get added at the bottom of the view.

below is adapter

```
 public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Cinema> lists;
    private int savedItems;

    public RecycleAdapter(List<Cinema> cinemas, int savedItems) {
        this.lists = cinemas;
        this.savedItems = savedItems;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView cinemaTitle;
        public TextView cinemaDescription;
        public TextView cinemaDate;
        public LinearLayout newLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            cinemaTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cinema_title);
            cinemaDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description_text);
            cinemaDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cinema_date);
            newLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.new_cinema_layout);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_cinema, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Cinema cinema = cinemas.get(position);
        if (cinema.getId() > savedItems) {
            holder.newLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.newLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        String title = cinema.getMessage().trim();
        String description = cinema.getDescription().trim();
        String date = cinema.getPublishedDate().trim();
        holder.cinemaTitle.setText(title);
        holder.cinemaDescription.setText(description);
        holder.cinemaDate.setText(date);
    }

    public void setCineams(List<Cinema> cinemas) {
        this.cinemas = cinemas;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cinemas.size();
    }
}
```

and the method which updates the list from Fragment is given below:

```
    @Override
    public void onCinemaUpdated() {
    cinemas = firebaseHelper.getAllCinemas();
    //Method which sorts the lists in descending order after adding new items into it
    sortCinemas();
    if (recycleAdapterAdapter != null) {
        recycleAdapterAdapter.setCineams(cinemas);
    }
}
```

I am not sure why am I getting this behaviour. Can anyone clarify on this?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: i think you have to call sorting after adding the items

Comment: are you ordering same list of items which is passed to recyclerview ?

Comment: After adding new items, you have to sort that arraylist again. After that call notifyDataSetChange

Comment: @Rahul Sharma, I did the same thing

Comment: @SANAT, Yes I am ordering the same list which is passed to the RecyclerView

Comment: this.cinemas = cinemas; in your constructor, change it to this.lists = cinemas; Or is it may just be a error while you were posting the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor and setCinemas method code to : Let me know if it helps..

```
public RecycleAdapter(List<Cinema> cinemas, int savedItems) {
        this.lists = cinemas;
        this.savedItems = savedItems;
    }

public void setCineams(List<Cinema> cinemas) {
        this.lists = cinemas;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```